# disable time in time dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dojo

Please suggest how to hide the past time from time dropdown list, displaying hours and minutes in each of the dropdown list.
My requirement is, based on the date user has selected ,past time should not be shown in Hours and minutes dropdown list or past time can be disabled so that users could not able to select the past time, as done for Time field in http://jsfiddle.net/8o23tbLu/13/
Below is the sample code:

```
<script>
require(["dojo/_base/declare", "dijit/form/DateTextBox", "dojo/date/locale", "dojo/dom", "dojo/_base/lang", "dijit/registry", "dojo/ready", "dojo/domReady!", "dijit/form/TimeTextBox", "dojo/parser"],

function (declare, DateTextBox, locale, dom, lang, registry, ready) {
    var pad, update_current_available_times, get_hour_string;
    pad = function (n) {
        n = n + '';
        return n.length >= 2 ? n : new Array(2 - n.length + 1).join('0') + n;
    },
    get_hour_string = function (t) {
       var hour = pad(t.getHours());
        var minute = pad(t.getMinutes());
       return 'T' + hour + ':' + minute + ':00'; //current time 1
    },
    update_current_available_times = function (seldate) {
         var useMin, now, time, pad;
        if (typeof seldate === 'undefined') {
            seldate = new Date(document.getElementsByName('userDate')[0].value);
        }
        useMin = 'T00:00:00';
        now = new Date();
         if ((now.getDate() === seldate.getDate()) && (now.getYear() === seldate.getYear()) && (now.getMonth() === seldate.getMonth())) {
            useMin = get_hour_string(now);
        }
        time = registry.byId("time");//user selected time
        alert("time: " + time);
        time.set("constraints", lang.mixin(time.get("constraints"), {
            min: useMin
        }));
    };

    declare("OracleDateTextBox", DateTextBox, {
        oracleFormat: {
            selector: 'date',
            datePattern: 'dd-MMM-yyyy',
            locale: 'en-us'
        },
        value: document.getElementsByName('userDate')[0].value, // prevent parser from trying to convert to Date object
        postMixInProperties: function () { // change value string to Date object
            this.inherited(arguments);
            // convert value to Date object
            this.value = locale.parse(this.value, this.oracleFormat);
            this.set('constraints', {
                min: new Date(),
                required: true
                // datePattern: 'dd-MMM-yyyy'
            });
        },
        // To write back to the server in Oracle format, override the serialize method:
        serialize: function (dateObject, options) {
            return locale.format(dateObject, this.oracleFormat).toUpperCase();
        }
    });

    new OracleDateTextBox({
        name: "oracle",
        required: true,
        onChange: function (v) {
            update_current_available_times(v);
            setTimeout(showServerValue, 0);
        }
    }, "oracle").startup();

    ready(function () {
        // Set the current time when starting up
        var time = registry.byId("time");
  time.setValue(document.getElementsByName('userTime')[0].value);
        update_current_available_times();
    });
});

</script>
```

Please find the code http://jsfiddle.net/8o23tbLu/13/ . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

there is an issue with dojo 1.9.0 library use dojo.1.10.1 or later

Here is the fiddle:    http://jsfiddle.net/7de4onun/27/
HTML:

```
Disabled Past time:
<input id="time" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TimeTextBox" required="true"
data-dojo-props="constraints: { timePattern: 'HH:mm:ss', clickableIncrement: 'T00:15:00', visibleIncrement: 'T00:15:00', visibleRange: 'T01:00:00' }" />
<br /> <br />
Date :
 <input type="hidden" name="selDate" value=""/><input name="SELECTED_DATE" id="oracle" value="" required="true"/>

Hours:
<input id="selHours" name="selHours" maxlength="3" style="width:50px;" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TimeTextBox" width="10px" required="true" data-dojo-props="constraints: { timePattern: 'HH', clickableIncrement: 'T01:00:00', visibleIncrement: 'T01:00:00', visibleRange: 'T24:00:00' }" data-dojo-id="dojoSelHours"/>

Minutes:
<input id="selMins" name="selMins" maxlength="3" style="width:50px;" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TimeTextBox" required="true" data-dojo-props="constraints: {timePattern: 'mm', clickableIncrement: 'T02:05:00',visibleIncrement: 'T02:00:00',visibleRange: 'T02:55:00' }" data-dojo-id="dojoSelMins" />
```

JavaScript:

```
require([
    "dojo/_base/lang", "dijit/registry", "dojo/ready", "dijit/form/TimeTextBox", "dojo/parser"
], function(lang, registry, ready) {
    ready(function() {
        var time = registry.byId("time");
        time.set("constraints", lang.mixin(time.get("constraints"), {
            min: new Date() 
        }));
    });
}); 


require(["dojo/_base/declare", "dijit/form/DateTextBox", "dojo/date/locale", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!"],
        function(declare, DateTextBox, locale, dom){
                declare("OracleDateTextBox", DateTextBox, {
                oracleFormat: {selector: 'date', datePattern: 'dd-MMM-yyyy', locale: 'en-us'},
                value: "", // prevent parser from trying to convert to Date object
                postMixInProperties: function(){ // change value string to Date object
                    this.inherited(arguments);
                    // convert value to Date object
                    this.value = locale.parse(this.value, this.oracleFormat);
                     this.set('constraints', {
                        min: new Date(),
                        required: true
                      // datePattern: 'dd-MMM-yyyy'
                    }); 

                },
                // To write back to the server in Oracle format, override the serialize method:
                serialize: function(dateObject, options){
                    return locale.format(dateObject, this.oracleFormat).toUpperCase();
                }
        });
        function showServerValue(){
            try{
                dom.byId('toServerValue').value = document.getElementsByName('oracle')[0].value;
                }catch(err){}

        }
        new OracleDateTextBox({
            name: "oracle",
            value: document.getElementsByName('selDate')[0].value,
            required: true,
            onChange: function(v){ setTimeout(showServerValue, 0);
    dojoSelHours.constraints.min= new Date();;
    var toDayMinutes=new Date();
    toDayMinutes.setHours(2);
    dojoSelMins.constraints.min= toDayMinutes;
            }
        }, "oracle").startup();
        showServerValue();
        }); 


require([
           "dojo/_base/lang", "dijit/registry", "dojo/ready", "dijit/form/TimeTextBox", "dojo/parser"
       ], function(lang, registry, ready) {
           ready(function() {
               var timeH = registry.byId("selHours"),
               timeM = registry.byId("selMins");
               document.getElementById('selHours').value = document.getElementsByName('tHours')[0].value;
               document.getElementById('selMins').value = document.getElementsByName('tMinutes')[0].value;
            });
       });
```

Hope it helps:)

Comment: +1 , Sorry to bother but first if i select the current hour, past minutes are disabled and again if i re-select the hour with future hour still in the minutes dropdown list minutes are disabled, they all should be enabled as we have selected future time for the second time.Please suggest. @Venkata Panga.

Comment: Yes True but to give an idea I've just given one work around to disable the past time and another case to disable the past hours and minutes after selecting date. <br/>Tomorrow I'll look into your future minutes case :)

Comment: I tried and got to disable past hours, please see http://jsfiddle.net/8o23tbLu/18/. I could not able to disable past minutes from minutes dropdown list. Working sample http://jsfiddle.net/8o23tbLu/18/ . Thanks  @Venkata Panga

Comment: use dojo 1.10.1 library and here is the complete solution with your updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8o23tbLu/20/

Comment: Thankyou it worked, but issue is i cannot use dojo1.10.1 version, i have to use dojo1.9.1 version.@ @Venkata Panga

Comment: As per my observation dojo.1.9.* may has bug to handle that minutes case. In your case you have to override _TimePicker popup or write own list for minutes.

Comment: Yes, i have tried couple of ways.I have modified get_hour_string function to disable past time when dojo1.9 was used and its working, similarly i modified for minutes field but not giving the expected output.Please see jsfiddle.net/8o23tbLu/25 . Thanks @Venkata Panga